# Aggregate and search nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Lets say I have a collection of documents that looks something like this:

```
{ "_id": "123", "arr": [ { "num": 1, "_id": "231" } ] },
{ "_id": "234", "arr": [ { "num": 3, "_id": "321" }, { "num": 1, "_id": "294" } ] },
{ "_id": "345", "arr": [ { "num": 3, "_id": "653" }, { "num": 1, "_id": "732" } ] },
{ "_id": "456", "arr": [ { "num": 2, "_id": "123" } ] },
```

How could I write a query to search for all "arr" objects where "num" is 1 and get something like:

```
{ "num": 1, "_id": "231" },
{ "num": 1, "_id": "294" },
{ "num": 1, "_id": "732" }
```

I have tried to use $unwind but so far been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Filters the documents to pass only the documents that match `arr.num === 1`
2. Deconstructs the arr field with `$unwind`
3. Filters the documents `arr.num === 1`
4. Replaces the input document with the `arr` document

.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
      $match: {
        "arr.num": 1
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$arr"
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "arr.num": 1
      }
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$arr"
      }
    });
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "231",
    "num": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "294",
    "num": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "732",
    "num": 1
  }
]
```